# Cumulative histogram

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function y=f(x), and I would like to plot in Matlab a histogram where I have the sum of ys for x in[n,n+1). 
Is there a function in Matlab doing that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cumtrapz`
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumtrapz.html

Example:

```
x = linspace(0, pi, 30);
y = cos(x);
yint = cumtrapz(x, y);
plot(x, yint, 'x');
hold on;
% exact integral
plot(x, sin(x), '-');
```

Comment: Wait, say I have a real x between 0 and 20, how do I get the vector of the 20 integrals of y with respect to x?